# Discord Python Delete Category and Channels within using ID

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
#deleted unused registered channels
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
#so that only an admin can run this command
@commands.has_role('Admin')
async def unregister(ctx, catID):
  cat = discord.utils.get(ctx.guild.categories, id = catID)

  #await ctx.channel.send(cat)

  for channel in cat.voice_channels:
    await channel.delete()

  for channel in cat.text_channels:
    await channel.delete()
  
  cat.delete()
```

This is the code I have currently. I have also tried it with client.get_channel(). I seem to get the error that category doesn't have access to .voice_channels and .text_channels, or that cat is a "NoneType". I am new to python and coding a discord bot so any help with this command would be great. Thank you!

The command is meant to take the categoryID you can get from right clicking and copying a category on discord. Then delete every voice and text channel under it. Then delete itself.

Comment: What is the error exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is nearly correct in itself, but can be simplified in many places.

`cat` is not necessary at all, so it does not need to be defined, because we can simply say the following:

```py
category: discord.CategoryChannel
```

Now we just have to enter the ID and the rest will take care of itself. Based on the definition we can now build the code further:

```py
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
@commands.has_role('Admin')
async def unregister(ctx, category: discord.CategoryChannel):
    delcategory = category # delcategory is our ID (category)
    channels = delcategory.channels # Get all channels of the category

    for channel in channels: # We search for all channels in a loop
        try:
            await channel.delete() # Delete all channels
        except AttributeError: # If the category does not exist/channels are gone
            pass
    await delcategory.delete() # At the end we delete the category, if the loop is over
```