# How do delete categories in discord py?

Tags: python, discord

Im working on a bot that will delete all channels and categories in a guild then add new channels, roles and categories kind of like a server set up bot. How ever I cant figure out how to remove categories. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Discord Python Delete Category and Channels within using ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67944442/discord-python-delete-category-and-channels-within-using-id)

Comment: I'm trying to delete all categories, that one you have to specify the category so no. Sorry

Comment: At least you can get information from that and re-design the code to your needs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you haven't provided an approach, I really don't know if you've done any research at all. There is a whole simple solution to this.

Depending on which method you work with, you have to rewrite the code a bit.

**Look at the following:**

```py
@client.command()
async def delcat(ctx):
    for category in ctx.guild.categories: # Get all the categories
        await category.delete() # Delete them in the loop
    print("Deleted all categories.") # Print the result
```

Here we go with a `for`-loop over all `categories` in the `ctx.guild`, as where the command was executed. In this loop we then delete all categories and at the end we get our `print` statement that everything worked.